# how to make footer stay at the bottom of page despite there's not enough of content

Tags: html, css

I tried to let the footer stay at the bottom on the "short page", which means there's not enough content to push the footer down.

this is what I want it to look like:
[image]

this is how it look right now:

[image]

this is the css code:

```
.footer {
  clear: both;
  position: static;
  bottom:0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5vh;
  padding-left:5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  color: white;
}
```

if I use `position: fixed`, it will stay at the bottom of the screen, but when it's "long page", it will also overlay the body as I scroll, like this:

[image]

`position: sticky` is the same kind of result.

if it's `position: absolute`, it will just stuck at the certain spot

I googled the entire day but still, really need some help.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, the `footer`-element goes inside the `body`-element.

On pages where you don't have enough content to fill up the viewport, you can set the `body`'s height to `100vh` which will fill up the entire viewport of the browser. Keep in mind this limits the height to only `100vh`, so you can't scroll further down the page. But seeing as there isn't enough content on your page, this shouldn't be an issue. Just make sure you don't apply this styling on other pages where you have enough content to fill up the viewport.

You can then either make wrapper/container-element for your content and apply this styling (you could also apply this directly on the `body`-element, minus the `height: 100%`). This will make the container fill up the remaining `height` of the viewport.

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
height: 100%;
```

By then applying `margin-top: auto` on the `footer`-element, the remaining space will be converted to the maximum `margin-top` value possible, thus pushing the entire `footer`-element to the bottom of the page.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

section {
  background-color: tomato;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section>
      section
    </section>
    <footer>
      footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#head{
height:10vh;
background-color:red;
}
#content{
height:80vh;
}
#footer{
height:10vh;
background-color:blue;
}
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'head'></div>
<div id = 'content'></div>
<div id = 'footer'></div>
```