# Why is there a space under the background?

Tags: html, css, background-image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCR3J.jpg)I want my background to be full screen, but I don't know why there is a blank space below the footerWrap.This is my code

```
body{
    background: url('./Images/login.jpg');
    height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.wrapper{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    
}
```

I don't know how to fix it

Comment: You could set `position: fixed; bottom:0;` and see if it sticks at the bottom, removing the space. But you must not have any conflicting rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make footer stay at the bottom of page despite there's not enough of content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340370/how-to-make-footer-stay-at-the-bottom-of-page-despite-theres-not-enough-of-cont)